# Adding images to a quizlist in a JSON file

Tags: json

I am trying to show an image within a question in a JSON file. This does not work. How do I add the images within a question?

```
{
   "quizlist":[
      {
         "question":"What football team does this shirt belong to? <img>brazil.jpg</img>",
         "option1":"Brazil",
         "option2":"Argentina",
         "option3":"Ecuador"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the IMG tag does not work like that. It is:

`<img src="http://yourImageURL"/>`  or  `<img src="/images/yourImage"/>`

I don't know how you are displaying you description in order to show the image. But try with that.